# "source" command in shell script not working

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, sh, dot-source

I have a file to be sourced in Centos 7.
It just works fine if I do :

```
$ source set_puregev_env
```

however, if I put this in a shell script, it doesn't work..

```
$ sh xRUN 
xRUN: line 3: source: set_puregev_env: file not found
```

this is my shell script : xRUN

```
#!/bin/bash

source set_puregev_env
```

can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong, or missing?

Comment: btw, this file is -rw-r--r--. 1

Comment: What’s the path to `set_puregev_env` and what is the working directory when you run the script?

Comment: I’m not so sure about the duplicate: It looks to me like `source` runs but can’t find the file. My proverbial money is on the file not being in the current directory.

Answer (score 19):

source is a command implemented in bash, but not in sh.
There are multiple ways to fix your script. Choose either one.

**Run the script using bash interpreter**

When you are invoking the `xRUN` script - you are explicitly telling it to be interpreted by `sh`

```
$ sh xRUN
```

To change and interpret the script with bash instead do

```
$ bash xRUN
```

This will make bash interpret the source command, and your script will work.

**Use dot command to make script bourne compatible**

You can also change the source with a dot command which does the same thing but is supported in both bourne and bash.

Change the line:

```
source set_puregev_env
```

With:

```
. set_puregev_env
```

Now the script will work with either sh or bash.

**Make script executable**

You should also run the script directly to avoid confusions like these by making it executable `chmod +x xRUN`, and invoking it like this:

```
$ ./xRUN
```

It will then use the command specified in the shebang and use the rest of the script as input. In your case it will use bash - since that is specified in the shebang.

Comment: In ubuntu sh is a symbolic link to a command interpreter, bash, dash or ash usually.