# How to active Virtual environment form python script(.py) without shell script (.sh)?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, virtualenv

I have a requirement to run my code in python virtual environment, for that I am trying to active the virtual environment through the python script only.

But getting error as:
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found

```
cmd = "source ./nnvm_ndk_tools_env/bin/activate"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
Above commands I have added in below script and run the script
python test.py

Output:
source ./nnvm_ndk_tools_env/bin/activate
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

Can anyone please reply?
I have to active the virtual env through python script only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["source" command in shell script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48785324/608639), [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/608639), etc. More generally, [command source does not work site:stackoverflow.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=command+source+does+not+work+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+from+Python+script

Answer (score 0):

Hi Firstly you have to install virtualenv then create a virtual environment activate that Virtual Environment and then install all python packages you want in that virtual env. Like below

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv myenv
```

then a virtual env is created in your directory go to that directory

```
cd myenv
cd Scripts
```

then simply run a file 'activate'

```
activate
```

you can install your packages here
Let me know if you still find problem

Comment: It is encountered with error as "activate: command not found".

Comment: You will find activate.bat  in Scripts folder. just type activate.bat there if you still find error post a screen shot