# How to fix the terminal "source" command on OSX Catalina

Tags: macos, terminal

I try executing the below commands in my terminal.

`$ source ~/.bash_profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile`

and the system returns:

`-bash: [[-s: command not found`

I cannot think of anything extra information to provide.

Comment: You just need to separate **[[** and **-s**, like **[[  -s**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept researching my issue and came across [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785324/source-command-in-shell-script-not-working)

I initially misunderstood the error message to mean the source command was not found. After reading the other post I tried running `bash .bash_profile` and the result was `.bash_profile: line 11: [[-s: command not found`. I had an error in my .bash_profile file. I commented out the line and tried running `source .bash_profile` and it worked.

The initial command not found did not relate to the source command, it related to the file I was running with source.

I hope this helps someone else.